# Is there a way to extend a virtual display in Windows 10?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, synergy, virtual-desktop, tightvnc

I have a friend who has two laptops and an external monitor. He wants to have one of the laptops connected to the monitor, while the second laptop functions as a third display for the first laptop. Is this in any way possible?

I have come across different solutions for OS's like Windows 7/8, including going into the Screen Resolution menu and "detecting" a non-existent display, but these features were fixed in Windows 10. I have also looked into Synergy, but that doesn't provide the same functionality that I was looking for (it simply lets the mouse travel between screens instead of allowing the other computers to act as extended displays of the first computer).

If I can get this virtual display working, I'm confidant that I can set up a TightVNC connection between it and the second laptop. I just need help getting it up. Thanks, all!

Comment: I have never heard of using a laptop has a secondary or third monitor to another laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duet](https://www.duetdisplay.com/) lets you extend your Mac or PC desktop to another computer's screen.